# How do you get ipod nano to display the watch face as the default view

Tags: ipod-nano, defaults

Is there way to set the watch face as the default display?

I wear the iPod Nano as a wrist watch and I would like it display the watch face first when I press the power button.

Note: I'm asking this question here mostly because I found [this form post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3315691?start=0&tstart=0) so comically high with noise vs signal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings > General > DateTime > Time on Wake (Set this to on)

Thanks comically high signal to noise post!